# Error opening Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on VirtualBox version 4.3.16

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I was working on my Ubuntu/Virtual Machine, when my laptop battery has discharged. After that moment, when I try to open Ubunutu on Virtual Machine I get the following error:

```
  There is no virtual machine with the identifier:
  Could not find a registered machine with UUID: {}
  Result code: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND {}
```

Am I going to lose my documents, files, etc.?

Has anyone faced this situation?

Answer (score 1):

First open YOURMACHINE.vbox in editor (Notepad++) and find `"Machine uuid="`

copy that Machine uuid to

```
C:\Users\[user]\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml
```

find `<MachineRegistry>`
and add line Machine entry, it should look like this

```
<MachineRegistry>
<MachineEntry uuid="{YOURMACHINE_UUID}" src="[PATH-TO-YOUR-MACHINE]\YOURMACHINE.vbox"/>
</MachineRegistry>
```

That should work

Answer (score -1):

Old thread, but I had the same problem. In my case the YOURMACHINE.vbox was empty. There should be a **recent** YOURMACHINE.vbox-prev that you can copy on top of the empty one and hopefully that does the trick. It did it for me.